# CentOS 6.5 applications won't minimize on lower panel

Tags: centos, gnome

I believe this question is related to [something](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/113846/strange-sosreport-running-on-centos-6-5-upon-login) that happened earlier today.

Right now, when I press minimize on any Gnome application, it dissappears, is still running, but I cannot get to it to restore it. Should I reset my Gnome desktop, and how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `gnome-terminal` issue you mentioned in the other Q&A is likely the cause of this issue now. I'd log out and log back it for starters. After you log out, I'd switch to one of the virtual consoles <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and login as the same user. From here I'd kill all the process that this user owns that might still be running after you log out.

Once complete switch back to the X desktop, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>, and log back in.

Comment: I wound up having to reset the whole terminal by removing the gnome application panel, and re-establishing the icons.

Answer (score 1):

In order to fix this quickly, I entered this command

```
rm -rf ~/.gconf/apps/panel
```

I did not see the answer, until I had done this, and do not know whether those steps would have fixed the problem by trying them first.